# Using vba to place numbers according to given intervals, how to speed up the program?

Tags: vba, performance, loops

I have a column of numbers and 11 intervals. I wanted to place each number in the interval that it belongs to, and also to determine if the number is close to the upper bound or lower bound.

For example: If the first number is 210, and it should be in my interval 180 to 365, and it is close to 180, so return "Lower Bound".

Here is my code, it worked however, too slow! I have only 5197 numbers, but it takes about 202 seconds to run it, more than 3 minutes! I wish to seek your help: where my program is inefficient, and how to increase the efficiency?

If I have even more numbers, or more criteria to add, the program must be even slower :(

Thank you so much!!

```
Sub test()

bgn = Timer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim T(1 To 12) As Integer 'My intervals
T(1) = 1 
T(2) = 7
T(3) = 14
T(4) = 30
T(5) = 60
T(6) = 90
T(7) = 180
T(8) = 365
T(9) = 730 
T(10) = 1095 
T(11) = 1460 
T(12) = 1825 

For p = 4 To 5200 'My first number starts at row 4, so total 5197 numbers up to row 5200
     For q = 1 To 11

        'My column of numbers are in column G
        If Range("G" & p) > T(q) And Range("G" & p) <= T(q + 1) Then

            Range("H" & p) = T(q) 'Lower bound number
            Range("I" & p) = T(q + 1) 'Upper bound number

            'Determine closer to upper bound or lower bound                
            If Abs(Range("G" & p) - T(q)) >= Abs(Range("G" & p) - T(q + 1)) Then
                Range("J" & p) = "Upper Bound"                
            Else
                Range("J" & p) = "Lower Bound"
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next q
Next p

MsgBox Timer - bgn

End Sub
```

Comment: Use variant arrays instead of looping the ranges.

Comment: You reference `Range("G" & p)` multiple times for each row - pull that out into a variable before you go into the `q` loop and use the variable in the loop.  Accessing the sheet over and over costs you execution speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example approach using Scott's suggestion.
On my PC this runs in a fraction of a second.

```
Sub test()

    Dim bgn, p, q, arrIn, arrOut(), v
    Dim rngInput As Range

    bgn = Timer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim T(1 To 12) As Integer 'My intervals
    T(1) = 1
    T(2) = 7
    T(3) = 14
    T(4) = 30
    T(5) = 60
    T(6) = 90
    T(7) = 180
    T(8) = 365
    T(9) = 730
    T(10) = 1095
    T(11) = 1460
    T(12) = 1825

    Set rngInput = Range("G4:G5200")

    arrIn = rngInput.Value                       'get all inputs in an array
    ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arrIn, 1), 1 To 3)  'size an array to take the outputs

    For p = 1 To UBound(arrIn, 1) 'My first number starts at row 4, so total 5197 numbers up to row 5200
         v = arrIn(p, 1)
         For q = 1 To 11
            If v > T(q) And v <= T(q + 1) Then
                'populate the output array
                arrOut(p, 1) = T(q) 'Lower bound number
                arrOut(p, 2) = T(q + 1) 'Upper bound number
                arrOut(p, 3) = IIf(Abs(v - T(q)) >= Abs(v - T(q + 1)), "Upper Bound", "Lower bound")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next q
    Next p

    rngInput.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = arrOut '<< place the outputs on the sheet

    Debug.Print Timer - bgn

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Really fast! So if I have other criteria or variable, just expand the 1 To 3 dimension of arrOut, to put everything in an array, right?

Comment: And I have some further questions please: 1. Can I make an array like arrIn = Range("G4:G5200")? Would it be the same as your method? 2. for arrIn, even if it is an n x 1 array, the column 1 cannot be omitted like my array T()? 3. what does IIf mean? Looks like an If statement. 4. To output to the sheet, what is the advantage to use resize? As opposed to something like Range("H4:J5200")=Application.Transpose(arrOut)? 5. What dose Debug.Print do instead of msgbox? Very much appreciate!

Comment: **1.**  Yes it's the same without the intermediate Range variable  **2.**  If you have a 2D array you should specify both indexes  **3.** Please Google this  **4.** Resize and Transpose are quite different things - Transpose will "flip" your data whereas Resize just defines the size of the range the data will populate  **5.** Please Google

Comment: Yes is you have more than 3 columns of output just adjust that 3 to whatever you need.

Comment: Thank you Tim! For Q2. What’s the difference between 2D array like the T( ) I made only a single index or an array defined as T(1 to 12) instead of T(1 To 12, 1)? For Q4. It seems resize will also wipe out any existing formats, is there any other way to populate data to sheet? Many thanks!

Comment: **2** An array can have one or more dimensions: your `T` has only one. **4** `Resize` has no effect on the underlying cell formats, and neither does assigning the data by setting the `Value` property.   If you're seeing something different from that then you could explain the issue you're having.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now I'm adding 1 more index for arrIn by using "Union" to combine data from different columns, and also added another 2 indices to the arrOut, for some other criteria in the same loop. The problem is, the data are going to be output now are in columns that are not adjacent: arrOut first 3 output are for Column H,I,J, however, the 2 new are for L, M. I tried to split arrOut like rngInput.Areas(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).Value for H,I,J, and then rngInput.Areas(1).Offset(0, 5).Resize(, 2).Value for L,M, but didn't know how to do this, or what's the best way? Thanks again!!

Comment: Create two output arrays - one with 3 "columns" and the second with two.

Comment: Also tried it seems Union brings me problem, after using Union to combine input data from different columns into a same array for processing, the output was nothing onto the sheet... Didn't realize where has gone wrong. I'm just trying to get data from different Columns, put into a same array, then use a single output array to output to different columns. Do I actually need 2 separate input array in the case that the data are not adjacent? And how to refer to like the first 3 indices only and then the only last 2 indices for output array?

Comment: Maybe time to start a new question with your current code and any issues?  Don't forget to accept the answer here...

Comment: Ok I see, so I'll create 2 arrays for output, what about input arrays, the only way is to create separate arrays as well?

Comment: You can't read a non-contiguous range into an array using Value, so yes you'd need one array for each area.

Comment: Thank you very much, really helpful! And sorry just realized that the check mark is to accept an answer. Again, thank you for your time!